# Django - Distinguish different types of IntegrityError

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm using django + MySQL. Sometimes, I insert duplicate data into my database, which causes django to raise an `IntegrityErrror`.

The issue is, django/python use this same error for several of the different [MySQL errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html). The only way to differentiate between them is to look at the error code. For example,

```
try:
    # code that raises integrity error
except IntegrityError
    if e.args[0] == 1062:
        raise CustomCreatedDuplicateEntryError
    else:
        raise e
```

My question is: Is this safe to do? If so, why isn't this implemented at a lower level? It seems like I can't be the only one who wants more fine grained control over IntegrityError.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Code to raise this error

```
class Foo(django.db.models.Model):
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=32, db_index=True, unique=True)

Foo(guid=a).save()
# this raises an IntegrityError with code 1062!
Foo(guid=a).save()
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is raising the integrity error?

Comment: @ScottWoodall, added :) I'm not sure if this will be helpful though,it's a very common error in django (plenty of questions on SO asking why it get's raised)

Comment: Isn't the reason just that those error numbers are database engine-dependent?

Comment: @AndrewGorcester, that could be it, but it seems like something like the django ORM which advertises itself as DB agnostic should translate different databases appropriately.

Comment: @djs22 I agree that that would be convenient, but I suspect that mapping MySQL error codes to Postgres error codes to Oracle error codes would be a fool's errand.  They do not necessarily mean exactly the same thing in every case, and the devil is in the details.

Comment: @AndrewGorcester, they already map ORM queries to different flavors of SQL, seems like that's even more of a fool's errand.

Comment: Well...  yes.  I'm glad there are some fools doing it though.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this safe to do?

This is not unsafe. Although by doing this you've created a coupling between your application and the database(MySQL). What if down the road you decide to replace MySQL with some other database solution? The error codes will be changed, and your code will raise inconsistent messages.

> If so, why isn't this implemented at a lower level?

Probably for the same concern I am having.

Comment: it seems strange to me that a db agnostic ORM such as django doesn't just map the error codes for multiple databases. See the conversation in the comments on the question for Andrew's take on this

Comment: May be that's the job suited for an extension, not the ORM itself. It'll require a lot of effort to do what you're suggesting for the ORM developers, with very little ROI.