# Django distinguish between the different IntegrityError

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Given an IntegrityError, how do I differentiate it between a "foreignkey error", "is null error" and "unique constraint violation" ? I could check the error message, but it is definitely not robust (vulnerable to changes).

I have seen similar posts:

- [Django - Distinguish different types of IntegrityError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575139/django-distinguish-different-types-of-integrityerror)
- [IntegrityError: distinguish between unique constraint and not null violations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490172/integrityerror-distinguish-between-unique-constraint-and-not-null-violations)

But they either don't work or require raw SQL.

Comment: For versions >= Django 1.6, You have the [`__cause__` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.db.IntegrityError).

Comment: One hacky way - In the exception message, look for specific keywords.